# RethinkDB node.js driver not correctly initializing global connection variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, rethinkdb

Running into a very odd issue that may be specific to my IDE, WebStorm, as I cannot reproduce this when executing via node in the terminal. In sample below:

```
r = require('rethinkdb');

var connection = null;
r.connect({host: 'localhost', port: 28015}, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection = conn;
});

console.log(connection);
```

my connection global variable is "null" when I try to log the result outside of the callback. However when I log the object from within the callback as such:

```
var connection = null;
r.connect({host: 'localhost', port: 28015}, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection = conn;
    console.log(connection);
});
```

I show a connection JSON object. This seems like a simple scoping issue that I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expected behavior.

Node.js uses JavaScript and therefore run your code in an asynchronous way.

What happens in your first snippet is that

- r is initailized
- You try to open a connection
- Print the connection
- And at some point later, connection is assigned conn from your callback

Comment: Is this simply then of looping against the `connection` object until it's value is no longer null? It takes less than a second for `conn` in the callback to return an object, but when I try writing this loop construct, the recursion fails to stop with a _"Maximum call stack size exceeded"_ error.

Comment: No, your connection is defined in the callback you pass to `r.connect`. The code that requires the connection should be inside the callback (or inside a function called by this callback).